# Avoiding calling both contains_key and get_mut on HashMap

Tags: hashmap, rust, ownership

I'm new to Rust and I met this situation which I think can be solved with more concise code, which is however rejected by the borrow checker. I'd like to know whether there's an alternative approach to it.

I'm trying to construct an inverted index. If the key is not previously in the `HashMap`, I have to create a new `postings_list` and insert it. If the key was already there, I will presumably have to only **update** the originally existing `postings_list`, instead of replacing it.

The code that is working (very long-winded):

```
if !terms.contains_key(term) {
    let mut postings_list = Vec::new();
    postings_list.push(posting_id);
    terms.insert(term.to_string(), postings_list);
} else {
    // try! can't even be used with Option... So I'm forced to write another match!
    // let postings_list = try!(terms.get_mut(term));

    match terms.get_mut(term) {
        Some(postings_list) => {
            postings_list.push(posting_id);
        },

        // It's impossible for this to happen...
        None => process::exit(999)
    }
}
```

However, I feel one call to `get_mut` should suffice:

```
match terms.get_mut(term) {
    None => {
        let mut postings_list = Vec::new();
        postings_list.push(posting_id);
        terms.insert(term.to_string(), postings_list);
    },
    Some(postings_list) => {
        postings_list.push(posting_id);
    }
}
```

The borrow checker says I borrowed a mutable reference twice, at `terms.get_mut(term)` and `terms.insert(term.to_string(), postings_list);`.

The problem for me is that apparently calling `contains_key` and also `get_mut` both would be much less efficient than just performing one check. Or did I get it wrong? Also, the above code is much uglier.

Am I doing this wrong? Or should I just not use `get_mut`, and should instead use `get` and then `insert` an updated `postings_list` again? Again, I'd think that would be much less efficient than simply operating on the original list stored in the `HashMap` itself. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Have you tried [entry](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry)?

Comment: @E_net4: Or high-level methods such as `insert_or`, ...

Comment: `terms.entry(term).or_insert_with(Vec::new).push(posting_id)`

Comment: @Shepmaster The point is I'm trying to append to an already existing vector, not create a new one. I wonder whether copying the original vector, appending, and then inserting would be much less efficient than directly mutating.

Comment: @Shepmaster I don't think your code does exactly what I did with my code. You created a new vector.

Comment: @JIXiang No, I did not; only when there wasn't previously a value.

Comment: @Shepmaster OK. it seems I shall learn a bit more about `entry` then. Thanks for the quick answer.